# How to install grub2 in centos 6.4

Tags: centos6

I am trying to use grub2 with CentOS 6.4.
But, the grub2 packages are available only in Centos 7.0 mirror list.
Could you anyone please let me know how to install grub2 in CentOS 6.4?

```
Basically, I have three partitions in the disk.
```

1) boot  - boot up partition
2) active - This is a primary partition where the currently running image resides
3) backup - This is a secondary partition where the backup image resides.

Currently, legacy grub is installed in the boot partition.
I want to upgrade this to GRUB2. I would appreciate any suggestions/pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is installing it from source. You'll need gcc >= 4.x and flex >= 2.6.x. Something like ( tested with centos5 ) :

```
yum remove -y gcc gcc++ flex ;   # maybe you will not need this part
yum install -y gcc44 gcc44-c++ ; # maybe you will not need this part
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc44 /usr/bin/gcc ; # maybe you will not need this part
mkdir -p /usr/local/src/ ;
cd /usr/local/src/ ;
wget http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/grub/grub-2.02~beta3.tar.gz ;
wget http://sourceforge.mirrorservice.org/f/fl/flex/flex-2.6.0.tar.gz
tar -xf grub-2.02~beta3.tar ;
tar xf flex-2.6.0.tar.bz2 ;
cd flex-2.6.0 ;
./configure && make && make install && ldconfig ;
cd ../grub-2.02~beta3 ;
./configure && make && make install && ldconfig ;
grub-install "${DISK}" ;
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg ;
```